# expressJS routing issue, simple stuff not resolving

Tags: express, express-router

I've recently moved all my route code into separate files, but now my route resolution is spotty. Here's a simple example -

My app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var dataLoader = require('./routes/dataLoader');
app.all( '/api/load', dataLoader);
```

My dataLoader.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/load', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Loader...');
});

router.get('/api/load/bob', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello Loader - Bob...');
});

router.get('/api/load/jim', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello Loader - Jim...');
});

module.exports = router;
```

/api/load  works fine, while /api/load/jim and /api/load/bob both result in:

```
Cannot GET /api/load/jim (or Cannot GET /api/load/bob, respectively)
```

I user app.all() instead of app.use() because I was having an issue resolving the main path "/api/load", the use of all seemed to fix that, but now I am not sure.

"engines": {
        "node": "^8.9.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
        "express": "^4.13.4",
        "mongoose": "4.9.8"
    }
any suggestions?

Comment: You just defined a route for `/api/load/api/load`.  I doubt that's what you want.  Also, you probably want to use `app.use(path, router)`, not `app.all(path, router)`.

Comment: How about just `router.get('/bob')`? I get the feeling it should be relative to what you supply in app.all

Comment: And yes, if in doubt just use app.use - I've never felt the need to use app.all personally

Comment: i understand all you suggest, and I concur, it's how i expect it to behave, I'l try again, and get back to ya'll in 3 min

Comment: All right - that seems to be working now - using app.use() and /jim.
I don't know why it didn't work earlier when I was tryng it like that...maybe something else flaky in my code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
app.all( '/api/load', dataLoader);
```

And, then in the `dataLoader` router, you define routes like this:

```
router.get('/api/load', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Loader...');
});
```

What you're actually doing is defining a route for `api/load/api/load` which is likely not what you want.  The paths are cumulative.

The `app.use()` statement should have whatever common prefix applies to your entire router and then the paths on the router itself should be relative to that.  In addition, you should use using `app.use()`, not `app.all()` for a router.

So, in your case, change the `dataLoader` router to this:

```
// whole router is configured at /api/loader
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Loader...');
});

router.get('/bob', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello Loader - Bob...');
});

router.get('/jim', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello Loader - Jim...');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried, when i first moved my code off to route files, to do this - but it erred, or couldn't find the route "cant fond GET .." - but I guess I had an error elsewhere, that I subsequently fixed, and didn't go back to try again.